# call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters) base64 image bind result not working if run from browser

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, apache2

In my project, I am using simple `php`, `mysql` library: https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class.
Here in `get()` method, I'm trying to get the image data which is stored as `base64` string to my `mysql` database table. When I am trying to send this request

```
$db->where("accessibility_data_id = ".$RequestId);
$result = $db->get("accesspath_data",NULL,Array("image_name,upload_time,image_height,image_width,image"));
```

the query is to:

```
protected function _dynamicBindResults(mysqli_stmt $stmt)
{
    $parameters = array();
    $results = array();

    //echo 'called for processing';
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    echo var_dump($meta);
   // echo $meta;
    // if $meta is false yet sqlstate is true, there's no sql error but the query is
    // most likely an update/insert/delete which doesn't produce any results
    if(!$meta && $stmt->sqlstate) {
        return array();
    }
   //echo 'problem meta';
    $row = array();
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $row[$field->name] = null;
        $parameters[] = & $row[$field->name];
    }

   //echo 'meta processed';
    // avoid out of memory bug in php 5.2 and 5.3
    // https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/pull/119
    if (version_compare (phpversion(), '5.4', '<'))
         $stmt->store_result();

    //echo 'version compare done'.$parameters;
   echo var_dump($parameters);
   try{
    echo 'inserted';
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);
    echo 'exit';
   }
   catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'exception';
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
    echo 'fetching\n';
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $x = array();
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $x[$key] = $val;
        }
        $this->count++;

        array_push($results, $x);
    }

    echo $results;
    //echo 'result processed';
    //echo print_r($results);
    return $results;

}
```

But if I remove the parameter image from the query, it works fine. Also this works if I use php command line execution.